# Spring 4.2.5 unable to see log messages

Tags: java, spring, logging

I have a web application (created with maven) with Spring 4.2.5 and log4j 2.1

log4j  Configuration file is under:

```
/proj/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
```

Seems like log4j is set up correctly, I am able to see logs from my classes fine (com.my.project.classes)

When I am using the log4j logger in my classes like:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyController.class);
```

The problem is that I am unable to see the log messages from org.springframework , 

I see both files and directory created C:/tmp/log2/Log.html and C:/tmp/log1/Log.html

But only C:/tmp/log1/Log.html will have messages - the other log/html file will stay empty

 What am I doing wrong?

this is my log4j2.xml:

```
    <Property name="fileName">C:/tmp/log1/Log.html</Property>
      <Property name="fileName2">C:/tmp/log2/Log.html</Property>
     ...

    <RollingFile name="MyRollingFile" fileName="${fileName}" filePattern="${fileNamePattern}">
        <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8"  pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="MyRollingFile2" fileName="${fileName2}" filePattern="${fileNamePattern}">
        <HTMLLayout charset="UTF-8"  pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>


    <Logger name="com.my.project.classes" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyRollingFile"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">            
        <AppenderRef ref="MyRollingFile2"/>
    </Logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Apache Commons Logging. In order to see the log events from Spring you would need to include the log4j-jcl jar.

Comment: seems like it didn't make any difference.